# Upload file don't call onFinish() method

Tags: java, gwt, gwtupload

i upload file by https://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/. Everythings work correct but sometimes my file is saved in folder but uploader don't call onFinish() method and everything is stop. I dont't have any message about error, file is saved in directory but uploader i stop. Someone have any idea why ?

Comment: which version of gwtupload are you using?

Comment: I change version from 0.6.5 to 0.6.6 but now my file call onFinish method but UploadedInfo info = uploader.getServerInfo(); info.message is null but infoObject isn't null. In version 0.6.5 this works fine

Comment: I rebuild my app and problem such as was in the beginning...

Comment: Have you tried to check what is the info in the wire?. Try  firebug, and focus on the POST request, it should return the info with the server info, after it the onFinish call should be fired. `uploader.getServerInfo()` is an object with many things, it always should have the `.size`, `.ctype`, `.name` properties, the `.message` is optional and depends if you fill that in your servlet

Comment: I get this from server : [INFO] incorrect response: C:\fakepath\Bez tytułu.jpg <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <response><field>GWTMU-05262228029563762</field> <name>BezÂ&nbsp;tytuĹ‚u.jpg</name> <ctype>image/jpeg</ctype> <finished>ok</finished> <size>187373</size> </response>

Comment: Can I change default response ?

Comment: You can add a customized message in your servlet (return an string in the overrided method executeAction). But in this case you are getting an incorrect response, it could be due because either the name having unsupported characters (try with a file which only ascii name) or either are using a different gwtupload version in server and client sides

Comment: When try file with ascii name everything is allright. Maybe I can change file's name which is going to response

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is in the encoding of the file name you are selecting for uploading, probably that is a bug in the gwtupload library. Please open a [ticket](http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/issues/list) in the gwtupload site with the more info you could (a .zip with a small eclipse project would be ideal) and I'll face the problem asap.